# Error building Python 3.10.13 from source code

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

**Ubuntu 23.10**

First i collected the configuration

```
./configure --prefix=/home/goodstealing/.python3.10.13 --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations
```

**--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions** are necessary for me to make flask_sqlalchemy work

Then I run **make -j** and see the following log

```
Running code to generate profile data (this can take a while):
# First, we need to create a clean build with profile generation
# enabled.
make profile-gen-stamp
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
make clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
find . -depth -name '__pycache__' -exec rm -rf {} ';'
find . -name '*.py[co]' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find . -name '*.[oa]' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find . -name '*.s[ol]' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find . -name '*.so.[0-9]*.[0-9]*' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find . -name '*.lst' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find build -name 'fficonfig.h' -exec rm -f {} ';' || true
find: ‘build’: No such file or directory
find build -name '*.py' -exec rm -f {} ';' || true
find: ‘build’: No such file or directory
find build -name '*.py[co]' -exec rm -f {} ';' || true
find: ‘build’: No such file or directory
rm -f pybuilddir.txt
rm -f Lib/lib2to3/*Grammar*.pickle
rm -f Programs/_testembed Programs/_freeze_importlib
find build -type f -a ! -name '*.gc??' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find: ‘build’: No such file or directory
make[2]: [Makefile:1928: clean-retain-profile] Error 1 (ignored)
rm -f Include/pydtrace_probes.h
rm -f profile-gen-stamp
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
find . -name '*.gc??' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find . -name '*.profclang?' -exec rm -f {} ';'
find . -name '*.dyn' -exec rm -f {} ';'
rm -f /home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13/coverage.info
rm -rf /home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13/lcov-report
rm -f profile-run-stamp
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
touch profile-clean-stamp
Building with support for profile generation:
make build_all_generate_profile
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
make build_all CFLAGS_NODIST=" -fprofile-generate" LDFLAGS_NODIST=" -fprofile-generate" LIBS="-lcrypt -ldl  -lm"
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
gcc -c -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall    -fno-semantic-interposition -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden -fprofile-generate -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include    -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Programs/python.o ./Programs/python.c
make[3]: gcc: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [Makefile:813: Programs/python.o] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:531: build_all_generate_profile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:507: profile-gen-stamp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/goodstealing/Python-3.10.13'
make: *** [Makefile:519: profile-run-stamp] Error 2
```

Updated
ls -la Programs

```
total 76
drwxr-xr-x  2 goodstealing goodstealing  4096 Aug 24  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 goodstealing goodstealing  4096 Feb 29 22:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing  4782 Aug 24  2023 _freeze_importlib.c
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing   266 Aug 24  2023 python.c
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing    67 Aug 24  2023 README
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing 49614 Aug 24  2023 _testembed.c
```

I need to build python from source code, please help.

Comment: The error says "Permission denied". Probably when writing `python.o` or reading one of the input files. Can you show the result of `ls -la Programs`, more especifically the permission bits?

Comment: total 76
drwxr-xr-x  2 goodstealing goodstealing  4096 Aug 24  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 goodstealing goodstealing  4096 Feb 29 22:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing  4782 Aug 24  2023 _freeze_importlib.c
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing   266 Aug 24  2023 python.c
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing    67 Aug 24  2023 README
-rw-r--r--  1 goodstealing goodstealing 49614 Aug 24  2023 _testembed.c